# MYSQL query returning 'resource id#12 instead of the numerical value it should return

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Not sure why, but this is returning the wrong value. I WAS getting this resource ID #12 back, instead of the Number value '1' which I am seeking..

the code which did this was:

```
$type = "SELECT account_type from user_attribs WHERE username = '$username'";
$usertype= mysql_query($type);
```

so I changed that to this:

```
$type = "SELECT account_type from user_attribs WHERE username = '$username'";
$type_again = mysql_query($type);
$usertype = mysql_fetch_row($type_again);
```

Now it just gives me the word array. I am completely lost on this. Help?!

EDIT::

The current code being used is :

```
  $username= 'lmfsthefounder';
  $type = "SELECT account_type from user_attribs WHERE username='lmfsthefounder';";
  $type_again = mysql_query($type);
  $row = mysql_fetch_row($type_again);
  $usertype = $row['account_type'];
  echo $usertype;
```

which returns like this: Home Login Register Usertype is

(This should display 'Usertype is 1' in my navigation bar)

Comment: I changed the code to the following:

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there. You have the row containing the MySQL results which is what `mysql_fetch_row()` returns. Change that to [`mysql_fetch_assoc()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php) which makes your code more readable. Then you just need the specific column value you seek which you van access by using it's name as the array key:

```
$type = "SELECT account_type from user_attribs WHERE username = '$username'";
$type_again = mysql_query($type);
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($type_again);
echo $row['account_type'];
```

[Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [red box](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Comment: I made the changes that you suggested. Now it gives me a null value. When I search the database with the same query, I get the column and value 1. How is it STILL not working :((

Comment: `mysql_fetch_row` needs to be changed to `mysql_fetch_assoc`

Answer (score 0):

Do you more direct access to your database such as phpmyadmin? If so run your query there, with the literal expression of course:

```
SELECT account_type from user_attribs WHERE username='lmfsthefounder'
```

what do you get back?